# Is it harmful for my ranking if search engines find too many of the wrong keywords on my site?

Tags: seo, search-engine, keyword, ranking

I have put some Java code files on my website. I explored Google's Webmaster Tools and it seems that it also indexes these files, and therefore finds many typical Java keywords (public, void, null, ...). One of these keywords appears 1500 times. In contrast, the first real keyword from my actual content is 31. highest and appears 42 times in total.
Does this harm my ranking when a user searches for one of my real keywords because search engines consider it an unimportant keyword on my website? Should I add a rule to my robots.txt to prevent this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword count in webmaster tools is just a count of frequency and doesnt mean your site will rank for those terms.

See here also >

> Q: Why do my Webmaster Tools stats show common phrases such as "buy
>   now" that are not directly related to my site? A: While some common
>   words and phrases are filtered by Webmaster Tools, there may be some
>   that you use which are not. Having these words or phrases listed in
>   your Webmaster Tools account does not mean that our algorithms will
>   view your site as being only relevant for those keywords. While
>   Webmaster Tools mostly counts the occurences of words on your site,
>   our web-search algorithms use well over 200 other factors for
>   crawling, indexing and ranking. In other words: don't worry if you see
>   keywords like this listed in your Webmaster Tools account.
>
> Keep in mind that this data may take some time to be updated
>   (Googlebot needs to recrawl your pages). Also, since all content from
>   your pages are used for this data, it's possible that it also contains
>   words and phrases like "buy now" which may not be that relevant to
>   your site on a whole.

https://sites.google.com/site/webmasterhelpforum/en/faq--webmaster-tools#strange-words2